# Returned types from stored procedure execution

Tags: c#, sql, datareader

I have a SP I want to execute and save the groos result aside (in a class field).
Later on I want to acquire the values of some columns for some rows from this result.

What returned types are possible? Which one is the most sutiable for my goal?
I know there are DataSet, DataReader, resultSet. what else?
What is the main difference between them ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the results and use them later (as you have written), you may use the heavy data sets or fill the lightweight lists with custom container types via the data reader.

Or in case you want to consume the results immediately, go on with the data reader.

Result set is the old VB6 class AFAIK or the current Java interface.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional way to get data is by using the the classes in System.Data.SqlClient namespace.  You can use the DataReader which is a read only forward type of cursor, fast and efficient when you just want to read a recordset. DataReader is bindable but you read it one record at the time and therefore don't have the options of going back, for instance. If the recordset is very big the reader is also good because it stores just one record at the time in memory.
You can use the DataAdapter and get a DataSet and then you have a complete control of all the data within the DataSet-class.  It is heavier on the system but very powerful when you need to work with the data in you application.  You can also use DataSet if the query returns more than one recordset.
So it really depends on what you need to do with the data after getting it from the database.  If you just need to read it into something else, use DataReader otherwise DataSet.